# Reordering an array from parse.com

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, parse-platform

I am getting an array from parse.com. I am using an array, to retrieve an array:

```
 fightList.whereContainedIn("objectId", itemListCard);
 fightList.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() ....
```

My first array; `itemListCard` is in a specific order. After I `findInBackground`, my array from online, (`objectId`), is completely out of order. This is because I am getting it from Parse.com, so it is added to the array as it is retrieved. I need to:

**1. Re-order array `objectId` to match `itemListCard`** or

**2. Retrieve `objectId` in order of `itemListCard`**

---

Java code:

```
HomeItemList = new ArrayList<HomeItem>();
    fightList.whereContainedIn("objectId", itemListCard);

    fightList.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objectId, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < objectId.size(); i = i + 2) {
                    HomeItem homeItem = new HomeItem();
                    homeItem.setHomeItemID(k);
                    k++;
                    //set Red Array
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRedName(objectId.get(i).getString("Name"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRedAge(objectId.get(i).getString("Age"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRedRecord(objectId.get(i).getString("Record"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRedHeight(objectId.get(i).getString("Height"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRedWeight(objectId.get(i).getString("Weight"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRedCity(objectId.get(i).getString("Location"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemRedExp(objectId.get(i).getString("Experience"));

                    //set blue Array
                    homeItem.setHomeItemBlueName(objectId.get(i+1).getString("Name"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemBlueAge(objectId.get(i+1).getString("Age"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemBlueRecord(objectId.get(i+1).getString("Record"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemBlueHeight(objectId.get(i+1).getString("Height"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemBlueWeight(objectId.get(i+1).getString("Weight"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemBlueCity(objectId.get(i+1).getString("Location"));
                    homeItem.setHomeItemBlueExp(objectId.get(i+1).getString("Experience"));

                    HomeItemList.add(homeItem);
                    }

                HomeListAdapter = new HomeListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, HomeItemList);
                adapter.addSection(" Fight Card ", HomeListAdapter);

            } else {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.d("Display Card", "Error parsing Card");
                Log.d("Card Error:", e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(databaseFightCard.this, "Could not retrieve parse info. Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

**Note**

The for loop is counting by 2 because this is the structure I am going for:

```
 objectId[0] vs objectId[1]
 objectId[2] vs objectId[3]
 objectId[4] vs objectId[5]
 objectId[6] vs objectId[7]
 ....and so on
```

Hence the need for a specific order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the order in which the items are returned using orderByAscending() and orderByDescending().

In your case:

```
fightList.whereContainedIn("objectId", itemListCard);
fightList.orderByAscending("objectId");
fightList.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() ....
```

See [Query Constraints section of the the Parse Android Guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-constraints).

Comment: That will order the returning array to be the same order as `objectId`? because the original array is in not order...

Comment: Yes, the orderedBy() will cause the returned array to be in order by objectId.  You would also have to sort your original itemListCard array by objectId if you wanted both to be in that order.